# Rest Filter with annotation

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-1.0

I am writing restful webservice and I have to write REST server side Filter with Static name binding annotation . I have two filter one filter have annotaion @one and another filter have annotation @two I have to put these two annotation on the Rest Webservices .

```
@one 
@two
public String getName()
{
return "xyz";
}
```

The logic in First filter is that It will check certain condition "say condition A" then only this will allow the request to hit this rest and the logic in Second Filter is that It will check certain condition "say condition B" then only this will allow the request to hit this rest .
But I have a situation that any of this two condition A or B is satisfied then also the request will hit this rest .
 If any one condition will certify then also the request will hit this web services , can you tell how to do this ?

Comment: The `NamingConvention` for annotations is the same as the one for classes and interfaces btw.

Answer (score 1):

There's `@Priority()` to control [filter and interceptors](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html) execution order.

> In case you register more filters and interceptors you might want to define an exact order in which they should be invoked. The order can be controlled by the @Priority annotation defined by the javax.annotation.Priority class. The annotation accepts an integer parameter of priority. Providers used in request processing (ContainerRequestFilter, ClientRequestFilter) as well as entity interceptors (ReaderInterceptor, WriterInterceptor) are sorted based on the priority in an ascending manner. So, a request filter with priority defined with @Priority(1000) will be executed before another request filter with priority defined as @Priority(2000). Providers used during response processing (ContainerResponseFilter, ClientResponseFilter) are executed in the reverse order (using descending manner), so a provider with the priority defined with @Priority(2000) will be executed before another provider with priority defined with @Priority(1000).

https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9816

Comment: Hi sajjadG, the link was broken. The new one is https://jersey.github.io/apidocs-javax.jax-rs/2.0.1/javax/ws/rs/Priorities.html

Comment: Hi @MincongHuang, Thanks. After Oracle donated JavaEE to Eclipse foundation all of its technologies moved to other addresses. Jersey moved as well. Thanks for the new link. I'll update the post for users continence.